# Problems in Webkit with scrolling, fixed positioned div, and flash

Tags: html, css, webkit, flash

I'm having a problem in webkit that is due to a bug in the rendering engine (or feature) that I can't seem to workaround.

HTML:

```
<div id="left">
    Content
</div>
<div id="right">
    <div id="scroll">
        <div class="video">
            <!-- Flash -->
        </div>
        Sidebar
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

#right {
    float: right;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

#scroll {
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewryno/pUaM2/1/

The problem arises when I have a flash object inside a scrolling div that is position fixed. When you scroll, everything works as expected until you mouse over the flash object. Once you do that, flash steals your focus and begins scrolling the document, not the div. It seems that this only happens in webkit.

The only workaround I've found is adding a div around the flash (.video in the HTML I gave) and adding:

```
.video {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

The problem with that is it moves the flash/div behind it's parent so while it's still visible, and the scrolling works, you can no longer interact with the flash.

Is this even possible to workaround? Removing the `position: fixed;` makes it work, so stealing of focus is not the issue, but rather the fixed position is.

**Update:**

Been trying a few JS solutions, but none have worked. Using the z-index "hack" so the z-index changes between -1/0 on scroll start/stop didn't work because jQuery doesn't recognize the scroll event when you are hovering over the flash. And covering the flash with a div and removing it on click doesn't work because your first click won't go through (and I can't make JS click the flash).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726601/stop-scrolling-page-after-mouseenter-to-flash-object


i have some problem , man. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

why are you using the old embed code? 
use iframe, it is becoming the standard.

also dont need to use fixed. use absolute.

```
#left {
overflow-y: auto;
position: absolute;
left:0;
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
}

#right {
overflow-y: auto;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
}
```

does this work?

http://jsfiddle.net/pUaM2/10/

Comment: I was using the old embed code as an example because part of the actual use case is for flash banner ads that don't have an iframe option. Sorry, I only just saw this because apparently I don't get email notifications.. :\ I'm just beginning work on this feature again so I'll try using that CSS.